# Flutter - packages for audio proccessing

Tags: flutter, audio, noise

I want to detect noise and disallow adding users to the common stream. Who knows some packages for audio proccessing for flutter? MB packages for native modules (android, ios)

I find some packages for example - coast_audio, but iam affraid that it's new package, and there is no link to api? only one example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple packages for audio processing you can choose from.

I suggest one of them:

- [**flutter_sound**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound)
  Supports audio playback, recording and audio level metering, which might be useful in noise detection.
- [**sound_stream**](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream)
  Allows streaming audio data from the microphone and play back the data in real-time. It's useful for real-time audio processing.
- [**noise_meter**](https://pub.dev/packages/noise_meter)
  Can be used to get the current noise level in dB and therefore might be useful to perform noise detection.

In terms of detecting noise, the `noise_meter` and `flutter_sound` packages might be the most immediately useful. They provide access to audio level metering, which could be used as a basic form of noise detection.

However, more advanced forms of noise detection (e.g. distinguishing speech from background noise) require more sophisticated audio processing techniques. For this, you might want to look into dedicated audio processing libraries - so external from Flutter and integrating them this way.

Comment: If you specify what you are looking for, I might be able to concise my answer in that regard.